# What does the 1st dropdown in the code window really mean in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a large legacy solution with several projects in it and I was looking at the 1st dropdown in the code window.  I thought that it referred to any other projects that use the same file that was currently displayed, but it appears to be doing something different.  The hover text states

> Use the dropdown to view and switch to other projects that this file (*filename*) may belong to.

That *may* part is what I think is a cop out to say that VS may get confused sometimes.  Am I wrong?

What I am seeing for the `stdafx.h` file in my projects is that from `project 1` it shows `project 1` and `project 2` in it, but when I go to `project 2`'s `stdafx.h` (which is a separate physical file), it shows `project 1`, `project 2` and a whole lot of other projects.

If I am wrong, what is this trying to tell me?

[image: Image of top of edit window]

Comment: It only matters in solution where a single file can belong to more than one project.  With different settings, the combobox switches the intellisense parser state.  A Universal app solution is an example, the App.Shared sub-project has the code that's used in both targets.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, I have more than one project and some files 'belong' to more than one of them.  However, why is it populated with projects that it doesn't belong to?  Is this buggy or intended behaviour.  If intended, then what is it trying to say?